# Help fixing IE Bug

Tags: internet-explorer

I need someone to help me solve these IE Bugs.

I need the navigation bar to look like how it in in FF. And because I'm horrible at IE Bugs I need your guys help.

http://new.monmouthchineseschool.com

also: I do know that what you look at link for the css it says 'moz', that is currently my default CSS because I have not set up any others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay guys, I was able to fix it myself.

rather than using another navigation script I just did some more absolute positioning and got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the site - and do see that Firefox and IE(7) do render differently - and the IE one does indeed look horrible.

The only suggestion I have, is to perhaps use a standard well-known toolkit to generate the navigation items etc: these are produced by Google and Yahoo for instance and have a certain amount of browser-detection in them - saving you from having to worry about it so much.

Maybe take a look at some of these:

http://script.aculo.us/

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/ (Java-based)

http://script.aculo.us/

http://www.dojotoolkit.org/

http://jquery.com/